# Image.FromStream gives Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I had this piece of code:

```
 using (var image = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(file.InputStream)) //throws error here
 {
     //for full hd 1920, 1080

     ResizeImage(image, 1440, 900, 70, fullPath);
 }
```

and it would not work giving error: Parameter is not valid.

I then change the code to this:

```
System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();

using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{

    file.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

    using (var image = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(memoryStream.ToArray()))
    {
        //for full hd 1920, 1080

        ResizeImage(image, 1440, 900, 70, fullPath);
    }
}
```

and it works fine. I am complete confused why this would happen? The image format is JPG and it is a normal wallpaper downloaded from a website.

Comment: What is "file" here? It really helps if you can provide as much context as possible so we don't have to guess. (I *suspect* the problem is that `file.InputStream` isn't seekable, whereas after copying it to a MemoryStream, the MemoryStream *is* seekable... but that's just a guess.)

Comment: After CopyTo add instruction : ms.Position = 0;

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sure, sir. The file is an instance of the class HttpPostedFileBase in .Net MVC. Basically user is uploading a file and I am trying to resize it.

Comment: Okay, that's useful information. I suspect I'm still right about it basically needing seek access. You could set `memoryStream.Position = 0` and then pass `memoryStream` to `ConvertFrom` without calling `ToArray` though.